# How to Include Crystal Report Into WIX On Deployment?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, wix

I have finished a project that contains reports designed by Crystal Report, and now I want to deploy it, I found a lot of ways to do it (Install Shield,InnoSetup...)
But I am relieved to WIX (Windows Installer XML), and I want to know how to include some packages into it like Crystal report, .Net Framework...

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redistribute crystal reports runtime as separate msi, and include it in a bootstrapper for example.

Also there are merge modules for Crystal Reports. You can include these in wix using "Merge" element. This is more or less equivalent to checking corresponding checkbox in VS / Installshield.

You can find the merge modules in your CR VS installation folder. Also it looks you can find the latest ones here: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

.NET Framework cannot be included as msm package; you should use a bootstrapper. Take a look here for example: 
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html